# How to display all console massage in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new in java and wanted to add a TextArea on my JavaFX program and get the console messages displayed on it. Exactly like what you get when you start a jar file on white CMD (Exceptions, prints and etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own implementation of `OutputStream` to do it:

```java
public class TextInputForwardingOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private final TextInputControl control;
    private final Charset charset;

    public TextInputForwardingOutputStream(TextInputControl control) {
        this(control, Charset.defaultCharset());
    }

    public TextInputForwardingOutputStream(TextInputControl control, Charset charset) {
        this.control = control;
        this.charset = charset;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        write(new byte[]{(byte) b});
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        final String str = new String(b, off, len, this.charset);
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.control.appendText(str));
    }
}
```

and then forward the output to that OutputStream:

```java
final TextArea myTextArea = new TextArea();

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new TextInputForwardingOutputStream(myTextArea)));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new TextInputForwardingOutputStream(myTextArea)));
```